# Assign a array of int in C but got an extra int 32767

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code in C:

```
int main(){
    int array[] = {1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    printf("%d\n", array[8]);
    printf("%d\n", array[9]);
}
```

When I execute it, I get that the result is 8 and 32767. I'm confused why.

---

update

sorry about the 3,3 thing.
what really confused me is the number 32767, if its a undefined behavior why is it always 32767? And I have discovered a weired thing:

```
int main(){
    int arrayB[] = {7,4,3,4,1};
    for(int i = 0; *(arrayB+i); i++){
        printf("%d\n",*(arrayB+i) );
    }
```

}

I wrote this, and the number 32767 appears again. AND The creepy part is if I change the array to any other length (delete or add numbers), it worked just fine!!!

Comment: In C, your array elements are addressed as [0],[1],...[8]

Answer (score 7):

You're getting undefined behavior.

You can't print the 10th element of a 9-element arrray, that's not valid code.

You're only getting `8` for `array[8]` because you have `3` two times in the initializer list.

Your array looks like this in memory:

```
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
index: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 data: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So, you can see that the data at `array[8]` is really 8, but that's the last element in the array. If you index with an index larger than `8`, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Expressed like that it's confusing. The array has 9 elements and he tries to access the array[9], but it is not correct because in C the first element is array[0] and the 9th is array[8].

Comment: @Carles Thanks, I had mis-counted due to the confusing `1,2,3,3,[...]` initializer.

Comment: No problem, it also happened to me at first sight

Answer (score 1):

The array has 9 valid positions but you have to take into account that they are indexed in C starting by 0.

So if you want the first value: array[0] ;

if you want the last value: array[8] ;

array[9] is not a valid position.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C, uninitialized variables get garbage values which happens in your case as array[9] is not defined because indexing in C starts with 0 not 1.

Answer (score 1):

In C, array elements are counted from zero to the length minus one. If you use the GCC compiler you can add the option `-fsanitize=address` to detect off-by-one errors like this.

Source:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

        printf("%d\n", array[8]);
        printf("%d\n", array[9]);
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation command:

```
$ gcc -ansi -g -pedantic -Wall -fsanitize=address -o test test.c
```

Output:

```
$ ./test
8
=================================================================
==4517== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff70a43794 at pc 0x400b2b bp 0x7fff70a43740 sp 0x7fff70a43738
READ of size 4 at 0x7fff70a43794 thread T0
    #0 0x400b2a (/tmp/test+0x400b2a)
    #1 0x7f1ff1180ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
    #2 0x400788 (/tmp/test+0x400788)
Address 0x7fff70a43794 is located at offset 68 in frame <main> of T0's stack:
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 68) 'array'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x10006e1406a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e1406b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e1406c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e1406d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e1406e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00 00
=>0x10006e1406f0: 00 00[04]f4 f4 f4 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e140700: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e140710: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e140720: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e140730: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x10006e140740: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap righ redzone:     fb
  Freed Heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==4517== ABORTING
```

It is also a good idea to always compile with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Array index start from `0`. So you should not access 10th element.

```
array[0] is storing 1.
array[1] is storing 2.
array[2] is storing 3.
array[3] is storing 3.
array[4] is storing 4.
array[5] is storing 5.
array[6] is storing 6.
array[7] is storing 7.
array[8] is storing 8.
```

When you try to access `array[9]` you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: To clarify, not only can it contain any value, but it can also crash the program.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I didn't knew that it can also crash the program! Thanks for the information :)